# Arch Linux can't detect my network interface

Tags: linux, networking

Yesterday, I was about to install Arch Linux on my new PC, but when I tried to configure the internet but no interfaces were found using the command `ip addr` and using `ifconfig` config doesn’t even work.

I also tried on Void Linux and Gentoo (and I was about to try on Fedora), the same problem occurred but on Windows the Internet seems to works fine.

My system specs are:

- **CPU**: Intel i7 9700k
- **GPU**: GeForce RTX 3060
- Motherboard: MSI M360 Montar
- **RAM**: 16GB

The output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> MTU 65536 qdisk noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd  00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the ethernet connection (not the wireless) you should first check that the controller is detected. Have a look here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Ethernet#Device_driver

Comment: The [B360M MORTAR](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B360M-MORTAR) network adapter is the Intel I219-V Gigabit LAN controller. Try to install the [Intel® Network Adapter Driver for PCIe* Intel® Gigabit Ethernet Network Connections under Linux](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html?ws=idsa-default#q=I219-V&sort=relevancy&f:@operatingsystem_en=[Linux*]&f:@tabfilter=[Downloads]).

Comment: @rs028 i tried to load the kernel module, but i got an error that i can't put here because when i restarted the pc i wasn't able to get an output from it again. But the error says basically that it failed to load the kernel module.

Comment: @harrymc Well, I can't install without the internet, i could try to put the driver in the ISO but I don't know how to do that now.

Comment: The driver is in a single archive file that you may bring over using any portable media.

Comment: sorry for taking too long to reply, i wasn't able to reply because a storm almost destroyed my city. well, this problem just solved by itself and idk how. thanks for the help I really appreciate.